# Inserting array into mongodb gives an error

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongoose

So here's my mongodbSchema:

```
Schema = new SimpleSchema({

room: { type: [String] }

});

Room = new Mongo.Collection('room')
Room.attachSchema(Schema)
```

Now when I try to insert an array into it

```
Room.insert(["hello", "dog"]);
```

it gives me this error,         "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Answer (score 1):

woops, rookie mistake.
Room.insert({room: ["hello", "dog"]});

Comment: Better just delete the whole question, unless you want to give yourself cred by answering your own... and then delete it :)